# Fractional FFT library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, fft

I'm looking for a .NET library that can do Fourier transforms (in 2D) on arrays whose size is non-integer powers of 2, unlike ordinary FFT algorithms.

The reason is that I'm working on an image processing program and want to compute the Fourier transform on images of arbitrary size without stretching or increasing canvas size (and possibly repeat border pixels to reduce Gibbs peaks) which I have done until now.

Comment: If the sample not power-of-two sized, it's not FFT anymore, but just a plain old regular FT, which is a whole lot slower. Artificially enlarging your sample and accounting for the errors thus introduced is probably still a better solution.

Comment: Nope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestein%27s_FFT_algorithm

Comment: As @Cecil says, FFT size does not need to be a power of 2 - it just needs to be non-prime - typically so long as it has small factors, e.g. 2, 3, 5, 7 then you can do an efficient FFT.

Comment: @Cecil: have you tried FFTW ? http://fftw.org

Comment: @Paul R: In the back of my mind, but I'm looking for a C# compatible fx, maybe you know about a wrapper?

Comment: @Cecil: sorry - don't know much about C# - is there no way of calling native code from C# (like with Java and JNI) ?

Comment: Yes, P/Invoke was built into the CLS from the start, similarly to JNI :) I don't know if was done from start - that's another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may possibly find it here:

- [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/)
- [Accord.NET](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/)

Comment: Thanks, I shall look into that.

Comment: Unfortunately, AForge.NET's Fourier class offers only FFT for 2^n and slow (N^4) DFT :(